# I can't get R to not put my binned data in alphabetical order

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a bar graph for publication, and I'm trying to show the change in operation types performed at our hospital before a curriculum implementation and after, "BR" and "AR" respectively. The types of operation are "Open", "Laparoscopic", and "Robotic". I would like the "BR" values to come before the "AR" values on my bar graph, but I can't seem to figure out how to get R to read them in that order (I'm fairly new to R and coding :( ). my data frame is named df

```
           bin type cases_per_month
1         Open   BR           18.35
2         Open   AR           15.50
3 Laparoscopic   BR            4.25
4 Laparoscopic   AR            1.95
5      Robotic   BR            0.10
6      Robotic   AR            1.15

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=bin, y=cases_per_month)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")

data <- tapply(df$cases_per_month, list(df$type, df$bin), sum)
barplot(data, beside=T, col=c("black", "grey"),
    main="Average Cases per Month,BR and AR: Ventral", 
    xlab="Case Type", ylab="Average Cases per Month")
legend(locator(1), rownames(data), fill=c("black","grey"))
```

because R reads "BR" and "AR" as atomic vectors, most of the commands I've tried won't let me reorder it how I want to

[image]

This is what I'm getting now. I also want my y axis to go up to 20, but I just need to google that, I'm sure

Comment: use a `factor` and set the `levels` in your desired order

Comment: I've tried `data$type <- factor(data$type,levels=c("BR","AR"))`, but R says that $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: The variable `data` doesn't contain the `type` column. So R says that. @ehandren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one's kinda tricky. Here's my solution:

```
# Load ggplot
library(ggplot2)

# Create data frame
bin <- c('Open', 'Open', 'Laparoscopic', 'Laparoscopic', 'Robotic', 'Robotic')
type <- c('BR', 'AR', 'BR', 'AR', 'BR', 'AR')
cases.per.month <- c(18.35, 15.5, 4.25, 1.95, .1, 1.15)
df <- data.frame(bin, type, cases.per.month)

# Reorder levels
df$type <- factor(df$type, c('BR', 'AR'))

# Plot BR and AR types side-by-side
ggplot(df, aes(x = bin, y = cases.per.month, fill = type)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

Also, welcome to R!

Answer (score 3):

Come on. You just need this.

```
data <- data[2:1, ]
```

Your figure is created by the `barplot` function in the `graphics` package instead of the `ggplot2` package. The `ggplot` line is useless in your scripts.

For your `y axis` issue, use the `ylim` parameter.

```
barplot(data,beside=T,col=c("black","grey"), 
        main="Average Cases per Month,BR and AR: Ventral",
        xlab="Case Type",ylab="Average Cases per Month", ylim=c(0,20))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Ven Yao! This really helped! I know it's child's play for most of y'all on here. Thanks, again!